# Centering memoir frontmatter and backmatter chapter titles

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, chapters, front-matter

How can I center the titles of the chapters in the frontmatter and the backmatter of a document written using `memoir`?

Keep in mind that the mainmatter chapters should not be affected at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your own chapter styles. For example,

```
% ===== FRONT MATTER CHAPTER STYLE
\makechapterstyle{frontmatter}{% Front matter chapter style
  \chapterstyle{default}% Or whatever you consider to be default
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{% Update chapter title printing macro
    \centering\chaptitlefont ##1}% Centred chapter title
}
% ===== MAIN MATTER CHAPTER STYLE
\makechapterstyle{mainmatter}{% Main matter chapter style
  \chapterstyle{default}% Or whatever you consider to be default
}
% ===== BACK MATTER CHAPTER STYLE
\makechapterstyle{backmatter}{% Back matter chapter style
  \chapterstyle{frontmatter}% Backmatter chapterstyle is similar to frontmatter
}
```

and, if need be, add these chapter style changes to the respective formatting macros:

```
\let\oldfrontmatter\frontmatter
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{\chapterstyle{frontmatter}\oldfrontmatter}
\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\chapterstyle{mainmatter}\oldmainmatter}
\let\oldbackmatter\backmatter
\renewcommand{\backmatter}{\chapterstyle{backmatter}\oldbackmatter}
```

Comment: I was in need of a solution without the "definition" of a new chapter style, since the class I'm using (which makes use of memoir, that's why I addressed it here) defines its own, and I didn't want to "hack it" to make it work...
Is there a way to "redefine" just the necessary parts of an already defined style?

Comment: To make things clearer, I'm using `abntex2`, which is a class most used to typeset graduate texts, like PhD thesis, using the rules of the Brazilian standard for these kinds of documents.
The customization on the standard style is considerable, and the way to make only this change would be to copy the defined style from the `.cls` file and base the new style on it.
This is really not optimal, because if the standard changes, or the way things are done in the class changes, then I would need to reflect them in all my document sources.